# Where can I farm Molten Lodestones?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The question says it all. Where do Molten Lodestones drop? I need 6 of them to make runes but I can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Molten Lodestones are found in Citadel of Flame explorable mode chests.

Citadel of Flame is a dungeon in Fireheart Rise in the Ascalon region.

Comment: Are you entirely positive this is the only place they drop?

Comment: [People](http://www.gw2db.com/items/19769-molten-lodestone-s#related:comments) say they can drop from (vet) mobs in Malchor's Leap

Comment: They're almost certain just rare drops off elemental type mobs -- but maybe only specific types.

Comment: So far I have got nothing but molten cores from chests :(. I guess I am just really unlucky.

Answer (score 2):

According to the GW2 Wiki, there is a Mystic Forge recipe to promote cores to lodestones: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_forge#Lodestones

The example uses Charged Cores, but any cores should work.